# When a kotlin lambda is effectively converted into java SAM?

Tags: lambda, kotlin

considering this bit of code

java side :

```
public class Executor {
    public void execute (Runnable runner) { /* do something with runner */ }
}
```

kotlin side:

```
val executor = Executor() 
var runner: () -> Unit = { } // expected Runnable
executor.execute(runner)
```

Is SAM transformation done at the variable declaration line `var runner: () -> Unit = {}` or at the `execute()` function ?

Is `runner` reference inside execute scope is different from `runner` declaration ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The conversion takes place at call site, i.e. when the `Runnable` is actually needed. Have a look at what is being generated by the compiler (represented in Java code):

```
final class FileKt$sam$Runnable$9c7e667b implements Runnable {

   private final Function0 function;

   FileKt$sam$Runnable$9c7e667b(Function0 var1) {
      this.function = var1;
   }

   public final void run() {
      Intrinsics.checkExpressionValueIsNotNull(this.function.invoke(), "invoke(...)");
   }
}
```

The above code shows that an implementation of `Runnable` is generated by the compiler, which takes a `Function` as its construction parameter. in the `run` implementation that function is simply being invoked.

```
//the call

Executor executor = new Executor();
Function0 runner = (Function0)null.INSTANCE;
Object var10001 = runner;
if (runner != null) {
   var10001 = new FileKt$sam$Runnable$9c7e667b(runner);
}

executor.execute((Runnable)var10001);
```

The call side shows how the lambda, compiled to a `Function` object gets converted into the proper `Runnable` instance.